# pipenv failure to initialize Python 3 enviroment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv

I have been trying to initialize a Python 3 environment but all my effort has been unsuccessful, it's giving me the error below:

```
[okorie@kalif table0009]$ pipenv --three
Virtualenv already exists!
Removing existing virtualenv…
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /usr/bin/python3 (3.6.6) to create virtualenv…
⠋Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/okorie/.local/share/virtualenvs/okorie-VkPqrO2f/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/okorie/.local/share/virtualenvs/okorie-VkPqrO2f/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

Virtualenv location: /home/okorie/.local/share/virtualenvs/okorie-VkPqrO2f
Warning: Your Pipfile requires python_version 2.7, but you are using 3.6.6 (/home/okorie/.local/share/v/o/bin/python).
  $ pipenv check will surely fail.
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently trying to use Python 3.6.6, but the Virtualenv is expecting version 2.7. If you are trying to use version 3.6.6, first ensure you have it installed by calling `python3 --version`. If it is installed, make sure `python_requires` is present in your Pipfile.

Comment: How did it pan out in the end?